# threading: search for a value and stop all threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to implement a search method that will search through haystack and return first founded index of needle.

> static  int search(T needle, T[] haystack, int numThreads)

My question: How can I stop all threads if one of the thread finds result?
For example: I am searching for 5, I have 10 numbers in array such that [2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 3] and there are 2 threads. So first thread will look for first part [0 - 5), second thread will search  other part [5 - 10). If thread 2 starts firstly and finds result quicker than other thread, it should return 6 and terminate thread 1 and 2.

Comment: Take a look at Java ForkJoinTool: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/java-fork-and-join-forkjoinpool.html

Comment: same homework with me lol?

Comment: @cihangirND may be .. which where re u studying ?

Answer (score 2):

The classic way of doing this is to simply have shared data between the threads so that they can communicate with each other. In other words, initialise some flag value to "not found" before starting the threads.

Then, when the threads are running, they process elements in the array until either their elements are exhausted, *or the flag value has been set to "found".*

In pseudo-code, that would be something like:

```
main():
    global array = createArray(size = 10000, values = random)
    global foundIndex = -1
    global mutex = createMutex()

    startThread(id = 1, func = threadFn, param = (0, 4999))
    startThread(id = 2, func = threadFn, param = (5000, 9999))

    waitFor(id = 1)
    waitFor(id = 2)

    print("Result is ", foundIndex)

threadFn(first, last):
    for index in first through last inclusive:
        if userSpecifiedCheckFound(array[index]):
            mutex.lock()
            if foundIndex == -1:
                foundIndex = index
            mutex.unlock()
            return

        mutex.lock()
        localIndex = foundIndex
        mutex.unlock()
        if localIndex != -1:
            return
```

You can see from that that each instance of the function will set the shared data and return if it finds a value that matches whatever criteria you're looking for. It will *also* return (without setting the shared data) if another thread has already set the shared data, meaning it can exit early if another thread has already found something.

Just keep in mind that the shared data, `foundIndex` in this case, needs to be protected from simultaneous changes lest it become corrupted. In the pseudo-code, I've shown how to do that with low-level mutual exclusion semaphores.

---

In Java, that means using `synchronized` to achieve the same effect. By way of example, the following code sets up some suitable test data so that the sixteenth cell of the twenty-cell array will satisfy the search criteria.

It then runs two threads, one on each half of the data, until it finds that cell.

```
public class TestProg extends Thread {
  // Shared data.

  static int [] sm_array = new int[20];
  static int sm_foundIndex = -1;

  // Each thread responsible for its own stuff.

  private int m_id, m_curr, m_last;
  public TestProg(int id, int first, int last) {
    m_id = id;
    m_curr = first;
    m_last = last;
  }

  // Runnable: continue until someone finds it.

  public void run() {
    // Try all cells allotted to thread.

    while (m_curr <= m_last) {
      System.out.println(m_id + ": processing " + m_curr);

      // If I find it first, save and exit.

      if (sm_array[m_curr] != 0) {
        synchronized(this) {
          if (sm_foundIndex == -1) {
            sm_foundIndex = m_curr;
            System.out.println(m_id + ": early exit, I found it");
            return;
          }
        }
      }

      // If someone else finds it, just exit.

      synchronized(this) {
        if (sm_foundIndex != -1) {
          System.out.println(m_id + ": early exit, sibling found it");
          return;
        }
      }

      // Kludge to ensure threads run side-by-side.

      try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch(Exception e) {}

      m_curr++;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create test data.

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      sm_array[i] = 0;
    }
    sm_array[15] = 1;

    // Create and start threads.

    HelloWorld thread1 = new HelloWorld(1, 0, 9);
    HelloWorld thread2 = new HelloWorld(2, 10, 19);
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();

    // Wait for both to finish, then print result.

    try {
      thread1.join();
      thread2.join();
      System.out.println("=> Result was " + sm_foundIndex);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Interrupted: " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

The output of that code (although threading makes it a little non-deterministic) is:

```
1: processing 0
2: processing 10
1: processing 1
2: processing 11
1: processing 2
2: processing 12
1: processing 3
2: processing 13
1: processing 4
2: processing 14
1: processing 5
2: processing 15
2: early exit, I found it
1: processing 6
1: early exit, sibling found it
=> Result was 15
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot

Comment: But why always result was 15  ? for example I added two more ones to array. Second thread is not returning any result ? I think thread 2 can find result before thread 1

Comment: @WhoAmI, that depends on where you put the ones, threading often makes things seemingly less deterministic. In any case, the output should indicate exactly how the search progressed.

Comment: @paxdiablo I created 5 threads, I put values to 35, 205 and 405. result always is 405. just one time I see it prints 205. but there is no result for 35

Comment: @WhoAmI, it's unclear how the array sections are divided between threads in your test but, if it's 1000 array elements at 200 per thread, what you're seeing is as expected. The first thread has to go through 35-odd elements before finding a one. The other two only have to go through 5-odd. So the chances of ever seeing the 35-element found is very slim.

Comment: @paxdiablo I got it, But I When I divide it into to classes TestProg and TestProgController (main class ) . It does not stops other threads. Other threads also working

Comment: @WhoAmI, I suggest you ask another question, actually posting the code that you're using. That'll make it easier to target the specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html), once first result is available then cancel all other tasks.

`CompletionService` uses a supplied `Executor` to execute tasks and 
 placing all the future results on a queue from which you can take the results in the order they are completed